# Redirecting multiple users to different pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to redirect multiple users to different pages based on their `user_Id` or `user_login`. but everytime when i login it takes me to the second user. How can i fix it?

For Example: When `user X` login i want to redirect to `Page X`, when `User Y` login i want to load `page Y` the same for all users

For the First User

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_login_redirect_2nd');
function wc_login_redirect_2nd( ) {
 $user_info = get_userdata(9100010);
if ($user_id == 0) {
  $redirect_to = 'http://example.com/'.$user_info->user_login.'/';
 return $redirect_to;
```

}
  }

for the Second user

```
 add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_login_redirect');
function wc_login_redirect( ) {
 $user_info = get_userdata(9100008);
if ($user_id == 0) {
  $redirect_to = 'http://example.com/'.$user_info->user_login.'/';
 return $redirect_to;
```

}
  }

Comment: Can I just point out that using `wc_login_redirect_2nd()` for the *1st* user and `wc_login_redirect()` for the *2nd* user is mighty confusing.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang i am trying when userX login i want to redirect to pageX, When userY login load PageY

Comment: You don't want to use two filter hooks. you want just one. Honestly, I can tell you exactly how to do this, but I need to know how you identify which user?

Comment: @incredimike Thanks! I want to identify the user by `user_name` or `email` or `User_id`

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't need 2 functions. If you *really* need it, and I can't see yet that you do, you could simply use some conditional logic inside the function. Also notice that there are 2 variables available at the `woocommerce_login_redirect` filter that you can make use of.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_login_redirect', 10, 2);
function wc_login_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
    return 'http://example.com/'.$user_info->user_login; 
}
```